# Dynamic method and args - Get rid of 'spread not yet supported for CPS transformation'

Tags: jenkins-groovy

I got below code running in [Groovy Playground](https://groovyide.com/playground):

```
def okFn(jiraTicket, comment='') {
  println "okFn: ${jiraTicket}: ${comment}"
}

def notOkFn(jiraTicket, comment='') {
  println "notOkFn: ${jiraTicket}: ${comment}"
}

def branchFn(logic, successFn, successFnArgs, failureFn, failureFnArgs) {
    if (logic) {
        "${successFn}"(*successFnArgs)   // <==
    } else {
        "${failureFn}"(*failureFnArgs)   // <==
    }
}

def main() {
    jiraTicket = 'ABC-1234'
    branchFn(1>2, 'okFn', [jiraTicket, 'successComment'], 'notOkFn', [jiraTicket, 'failureComment'])
}

main()
```

But in the code marked with '<==' will always get 'spread not yet supported for CPS transformation'. How do I get rid of it? Also, could I specify which arguments going to which? E.g. `[jiraTicket:jiraTicket, comment: 'someComment']`. Thanks in advance.

Please note that if I put '@NonCPS' the branchFn won't call 'okFn' / 'notOkFn' as expected.

In case you are wonder what my code looks like in pipeline:

```
node() {
  stage ('blah') {
    jiraTicket = 'ABC-1234'
    branchFn(1>2, 'okFn', [jiraTicket, 'successComment'], 'notOkFn', [jiraTicket, 'failureComment'])
  }
}

def okFn(...) {...}
def notOkFn(...) {...}
def branchFn(...) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

I admit this is not a good answer, just a workaround:

```
node() {
  stage ('blah') {
    jiraTicket = 'ABC-1234'
    branchFn(1>2, 'okFn', [jiraTicket, 'successComment'], 'notOkFn', [jiraTicket, 'failureComment'])
  }
}

def okFn(...) {...}
def notOkFn(...) {...}

@NonCPS
def callMethod(def fnName, def fnArgs) {
  "${fnName}(*fnArgs)
}

def branchFn(logic, successFn, successFnArgs, failureFn, failureFnArgs) {
    if (logic) {
        callMethod(successFn, successFnArgs)
    } else {
        callMethod(failureFn, failureFnArgs)
    }
}
```